# What is the gcd of $x^3-2$ and $x^2+3ax+3a^2$?

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to understand Galois theory.

$f(x)= x^3-2$, with $a$, $b$ and $c$ as roots.

Galois resolvent $V_0= a+2b+3c$, $V_1= c+2a+3b$,... etc till $V_5=a+2c+3b$

assume $X=V_0$

$F(X)=(X-V_0)(X-V_5)$

this will lead to a polynomial in $X$ with coefficients in $a,b$ and $c$. These coefficients will be symmetric so they can be represented using just one of the roots, in this case $a$.

$F(X)=X^2+3aX+3a^2$

$F(X,a)=X^2+3aX+3a^2$

I am clear till this point, my confusion starts with the following...

the article claims that $(x-a)$ is a common factor of $F(X,a)$ and $f(x)$

I can accept that it is a factor of $f(x)=x^3-2$ as "$a$" is a root of $f(x)$, but how is it a factor of $F(X,a)$. $V_0$ is a factor and $V_5$ is a factor but why "$a$"?

In any case when I plug in "$a$" into $F(X,a)$ I get $F(X,a)=7a^2$ which cannot equal $0$.

The article then goes on to state that the g.c.d of $F(X,a)$ and $f(x)$
is $d(Y)=(2V_0^2Y+V_0^3-6)/3$.

I just can't figure out how the g.c.d is computed, some help in this would be greatly appreciated.

To summarize my questions are...

1. Why is $(x-a)$ a common factor of $F(X,a)$ and $f(x)$?
2. How is the g.c.d of $F(X,a)$ and $f(x)$ computed?

Thank you for your time. I am truly at my wits end.

Comment: i got $1$ as the searched GCD

Comment: I'm providing the link to the paper http://download-v2.springer.com/static/pdf/770/bbm%253A978-1-85233-850-3%252F1.pdf?token2=exp=1432261120~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F770%2Fbbm%25253A978-1-85233-850-3%25252F1.pdf*~hmac=4de14671c4df493fe8a84982fe9083ae27277a8f6da519877fc67ce076ba5b14

Comment: I changed t0 to V0 ...personal preferences